# Python version clashes and symbolic links

Tags: python, raspbian, symlink

I am wanting to use Python 3.7 on Raspberry Pi OS is Raspbian. I know Raspbian comes installed with Python 2 already and not able to uninstall that. I have Python 2, Python 3.5, and Python 3.7. That problem I am having is symbolic links, I need to install some libraries with Pip, which should be called Pip3. After doing a Pip3 --version the results are for Python3.5 which need to be for Python 3.7. Pip 3.7 does not exist so I am not sure what or where pip for Python 3.7 is.

This is what I am building [link](https://www.adeept.com/picar-b_p0117.html)
To install the software I can either use setup.py or manually go through and install everything. Here is the code that setup.py uses.

```
import os
import time

def replace_num(file,initial,new_num):  
    newline=""
    str_num=str(new_num)
    with open(file,"r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if(line.find(initial) == 0):
                line = (str_num+'\n')
            newline += line
    with open(file,"w") as f:
        f.writelines(newline)

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo apt-get update") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo apt-get -y upgrade") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo apt-get install -y i2c-tools") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo pip3 install adafruit-pca9685") == 0:
        break

try:
    #replace_num("/boot/config.txt",'#dtparam=spi=on','dtparam=spi=on')
    replace_num("/boot/config.txt",'#dtparam=i2c_arm=on','dtparam=i2c_arm=on\nstart_x=1\n')
    #replace_num("/boot/config.txt",'#dtparam=i2s=on','dtparam=i2s=on')
except:
    print('try again')

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo pip3 install pip setuptools wheel") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo apt-get install -y swig") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo apt-get install -y portaudio19-dev python3-all-dev python3-pyaudio") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo pip3 install pyaudio") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo apt-get install -y flac") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinxbase/5prealpha/sphinxbase-5prealpha.tar.gz/download -O sphinxbase.tar.gz") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/pocketsphinx/5prealpha/pocketsphinx-5prealpha.tar.gz/download -O pocketsphinx.tar.gz") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo tar -xzvf sphinxbase.tar.gz") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo tar -xzvf pocketsphinx.tar.gz") == 0:
        break

try:
    os.system("cd sphinxbase-5prealpha/ && ./configure -enable-fixed && make && sudo make install")
    os.system("sudo pip3 install pocketsphinx")
except:
    pass

try:
    os.system("cd pocketsphinx-5prealpha/ && ./configure && make && sudo make install")
    os.system("sudo pip3 install SpeechRecognition")
except:
    pass

try:
    os.system("sudo pip3 install pocketsphinx")
except:
    pass

try:
    os.system("sudo pip3 install SpeechRecognition")
except:
    pass

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo apt-get install -y bison libasound2-dev swig") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo apt-get install -y python3.7 python3-dev python3-pip build-essentsudo apt-get install python3.7l libpulse-dev") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo apt-get install -y libopencv-dev") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo apt-get install -y python-opencv") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo pip3 install imutils") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo pip3 install opencv-python") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo apt-get install -y libatlas-base-dev libjasper-dev libqtgui4 python3-pyqt5 libqt4-test") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo pip3 install zmq pybase64") == 0:   ####
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo pip3 install rpi_ws281x") == 0:
        break

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap") == 0:
        break

try:
    os.system("sudo cd //home/pi/adeept_picar-b/server/create_ap && sudo make install")
except:
    pass

for x in range(1,4):
    if os.system("sudo apt-get install -y util-linux procps hostapd iproute2 iw haveged dnsmasq") == 0:
        break

try:
    os.system('sudo mknod("//home/pi/.config/autostart/car.desktop")')
    with open("//home/pi/.config/autostart/car.desktop",'w') as file_to_write:
        file_to_write.write("[Desktop Entry]\n   Name=Car\n   Comment=Car\n   Exec=sudo python3 //home/pi/adeept_picar-b/server/server.py\n   Icon=false\n   Terminal=false\n   MutipleArgs=false\n   Type=Application\n   Catagories=Application;Development;\n   StartupNotify=true")
except:
    pass

os.system("sudo cp -f //home/pi/adeept_picar-b/server/set.txt /home/pi/set.txt")

try:
    os.system("sudo pip3 install pocketsphinx")
except:
    pass

print('restarting')

os.system("sudo reboot")
```

I have tried installing both ways, I believe the reason for this is the programs are to use Python3.7 but Python3.5 is installing through setup.py.

So now the OS has Python3.5 Python3.7 and Python2 installed, I need to use pip to install packages and i am not able to find Python3.7 pip. the command `pip3` returns "python3.5" the command `pip3.7` does not exist. How am I able to remove the symbolic link for pip3 from Python3.5 to Pyton3.7
I have spent to long on this install to reformat and start over so that isn't an option.

Comment: The question is not quite clear but I'd say, install `virtualenv`. Create a virtual environment with the python version you want and then you can install packages (and upgrade pip if you need to)

Comment: I have edited so hopefully the question is more precise.

Comment: Is there any problem with using versions? I don't see any errors mentioned on your question

Comment: I believe some of the syntax is different between 3.5 and 3.7. I do know the program was written in 3.7. As far as preference no I do not care to use either 3.5 or 3.7.

Comment: If you're worried about your script not working with 3.5 and require it to use 3.7, just run `python3.7 script.py`

Comment: I understand that, the problem is pip3 is installing all packages to python3.5 and not to python3,7. So when I run the script with python3.7 setup.py none of the libraries are being installed to the right place

Comment: Now I see where your problem is. Try this `sudo python3.7 -m pip install [package_name]`